# Issue with assigning Google Map Autocomplete results to variables

Tags: google-maps

I have issue with with this line: 
    var user-city = addressObj[j].long_name;
I see proper value in console log but can't assign it to the variable.

```
function onPlaceChanged() {


    var places = autocomplete.getPlace();
    //console.log(places);
    //    var place = places[0];
    console.log(places);
    console.log(places.address_components);
    user_home_address = places.name;


for(var i = 0; i < places.address_components.length; i += 1) {
  var addressObj = places.address_components[i];

  for(var j = 0; j < addressObj.types.length; j += 1) {
    if (addressObj.types[j] === 'locality') {
      // console.log(addressObj.types[j]); // confirm that this is 'city'
     var user-city = addressObj[j].long_name;
      // console.log(addressObj.long_name); // confirm that this is the city name

    }
  }

  for(var j = 0; j < addressObj.types.length; j += 1) {
    if (addressObj.types[j] === 'administrative_area_level_1') {
      // console.log(addressObj.types[j]); // confirm that this is 'province'
      // console.log(addressObj.short_name); // confirm that this is the province name

    }
  }


}
```

Comment: `user-city` is not valid JavaScript identifier. `-` is not allowed.

Comment: `addressObj[j].long_name;` doesn't exist, should be `addressObj.long_name;` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d7ya/).  FYI - both these issues are reported by the javascript console in Chrome.